# Elusive bug when using mathalfa with amsart

Tags: errors, debugging, amsart

I got a strange bug using the two aforementioned packages when I try to build the TOC. The bug happens only after I typeset twice with pdfLaTeX and forbids me to build the TOC.

Edit : following comments and answer from cfr I post here a better MWE that shows the problem actually comes from a conflict between amsart and mathalfa when building the TOC and using some specific options ... I would really like somebody to find a way of correcting this conflict ...

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[frak=boondox]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents 
\scriptsize $u$
\section{$\mathfrak{m}$}
\end{document}
```

And below here is an extract of what I get as a message on my console window.

> ```
> Use of \reserved@a doesn't match its definition.
> \reserved@b ->\relax 
>                      \ifmmode \else \non@alpherr \mathfrak  \fi \use@mathgro...
> ```

Edit 2: does anybody know if and when this bug could be corrected ? (in Latex or in the mathalfa package ?)

Comment: I have edited your subject but don't like to edit your content too much. I suggest editing it yourself as TikZ does not seem to have anything to do with the error, but amsart does. Feel free to use the MWE I've put in an answer below if you wish. If you do so, please ping me and I will delete it as it is not an 'answer' but is too long for a comment.

Comment: `\scriptsize` does not take an argument. It is a switch. `{\scriptsize usual work}` is probably what you want. Do you want me to delete my answer now? I'm happy to do so - I'm just not sure if that's what you'd like me to do or not since we've got discussion going in comments with barbara. (barbara can help you if anybody can.)

Comment: @cfr If I use properly \scriptsize as a switch the bug disappears .... unless I put the content in {} or $...$. I like your answer because it did a much better work than I did with my first MWE to pinpoint the true conflict. Unfortunately, if somebody find a way to correct it using the same packages I will mark it as the complete answer I was looking for. Thank you for your help !

Comment: That's odd. It does not disappear for me. But you do need to invoke maths mode, definitely. Anyway, your current example uses it as a switch ;).

Comment: The error is produced because `amsart` defines `\mathfrak` by loading `amsfonts` and somehow LaTeX doesn't like to have such commands redefined. The problem shows up when doing a font change because LaTeX makes some global definitions that confuse it because of how math alphabet changing commands are defined. The minimal example is `\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[frak=boondox]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
{\small $\mathfrak{m}$}
$\mathfrak{m}$
\end{document}` I'm afraid there is no way around the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a “feature” of LaTeX, I'm afraid.

Since `amsart` automatically loads `amsfonts`, which defines `\mathfrak`; it appears that redefining commands defined with `\DeclareMathAlphabet` is not possible with the current kernel. The problem shows up with a very minimal document:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[frak=boondox]{mathalfa}

\begin{document}

{\small $\mathfrak{m}$}
$\mathfrak{m}$

\end{document}
```

because the font changing command causes `\mathfrak` to do some global assignments that, in a sense, “resurrect” the previous definition of `\mathfrak` leaving the system in an unstable state.

Workaround if you don't need the full force of `amsfonts`:

```
% pretend that amsfonts.sty has already been loaded
\expandafter\def\csname ver@amsfonts.sty\endcsname{3000/12/31}
% load the msb symbol font that's needed for \dh
\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
% end of the hack

\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[frak=boondox]{mathalfa}

\begin{document}

{\small $\mathfrak{m}$}
$\mathfrak{m}$

\end{document}
```

Actually, there is a possibly better way to solve the issue, by redefining `\mathfrak` using `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet` that shouldn't resurrect the old definition, because math fonts defined with `\DeclareMathAlphabet` use a different mechanism that avoids wasting math families if the alphabet is not used in the document; since you'll be using Fraktur, this doesn't really matter.

The trick is to manually do what `mathalfa` does automatically, but using `\DeclareSymbolFont`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\def\mathalfa@frakscaled{s*[1]}
\makeatother
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{BOONDOX-frak}{\skewchar \font =45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{BOONDOX-frak}{m}{n}{
    <-> \mathalfa@frakscaled  BOONDOX-r-frak}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{BOONDOX-frak}{b}{n}{
    <-> \mathalfa@frakscaled  BOONDOX-b-frak}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{boondoxfrak}{U}{BOONDOX-frak}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{boondoxfrak}{bold}{U}{BOONDOX-frak}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathfrak}{boondoxfrak}

\begin{document}

{\small $\mathfrak{m}$}
$\mathfrak{m}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfectly clear. You explained my problem (which has nothing to do with the building of the TOC by the way) and find a workaround.

Comment: @brunoh I added a possibly cleaner workaround

Comment: Not to use the full power of amsfonts is actually a bit difficult for my actual document (lots of mathbb fonts ...) if I choose to use your hack. I think it is easier for me to get rid of the problem by not using the mathalfa package frak option that is just there for esthetic reason. It was a nasty bug I think, and a pity there is such incompatibility difficult to detect ...

Comment: @brunoh The new workaround allows loading `amsfonts`.

Comment: The new workaround is much more convenient for me. Thank you very much for your extra and bright effort.

Comment: It is also nice because I can still use before your workaround the mathalfa package with other options like mathcal ...

Comment: @brunoh @egreg You don't need to switch to `\DeclareSymbolFont`. I played around with this yesterday and found that I could not reproduce the error even when I copied the lines exactly from `mathalfa.sty`. I've posted the code I got working yesterday [below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256943/). Do you know why this works? As I understand your diagnosis, it shouldn't.

Comment: Or do you need to switch for later reasons...?

Comment: thankyouthankyouthankyou!!!  this is definitely something we will need to be aware of with the new latex in tex live 2015.  please send me any other incompatibilities you encounter with the new latex.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Me too ! I have discovered this nasty one and I would have loved a thankyou from Barbara Beeton herself ! But obviously egreg have done the hard work ... I am just kidding :=)

Comment: @brunoh -- you get thanked too, for reporting the problem.  but, as you say, egreg has done the digging, which will probably save me at least a few hours.  (for the record, though, your report is the first to show that the latex 2015 version will *not* go into mass production without a whimper.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton you are 100 % right of course ! my message was a bit of a joke. Sorry for that ! but seriously come back well and safe and then you can work on our beloved latex 2015 :)

Answer (score 2):

The error has nothing to do with TikZ. It appears to be an incompatibility between `mathalfa`, `amsart`, `\scriptsize $something$`.... This is not a complete diagnosis but it narrows it down a bit. (At least we can eliminate TikZ.)

Minimal example I can get to reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass{amsart}% substitute article for working code
\usepackage
  [
    frak=boondox
  ]{mathalfa}% remove frak option for working code

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents% remove for working code

{\scriptsize% remove \scriptsize for working code
  abc $a$ }% remove $a$ for working code

\section{$\mathfrak{m}$}% use text or non-frak maths here for working code
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

Yesterday, I established that copying the relevant lines to configure `\mathfrak` from `mathalfa.sty` allowed the code to compile.

```
\documentclass{amsart}% substitute article for working code
\makeatletter
\def\mathalfa@frakscaled{s*[1.0]}
  \DeclareFontFamily{U}{BOONDOX-frak}{\skewchar \font =45}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{BOONDOX-frak}{m}{n}{
    <-> \mathalfa@frakscaled  BOONDOX-r-frak}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{BOONDOX-frak}{b}{n}{
    <-> \mathalfa@frakscaled  BOONDOX-b-frak}{}
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{U}{BOONDOX-frak}{m}{n}
  \SetMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{bold}{U}{BOONDOX-frak}{b}{n}
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbfrak} {U}{BOONDOX-frak}{b}{n}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents% remove for working code

{\scriptsize% remove \scriptsize for working code
  abc $a$ }% remove $a$ for working code

\section{$\mathfrak{m}$}% use text or non-frak maths here for working code
\end{document}
```

The above works fine. But notice that I'm using *exactly the commands from `mathalfa.sty`*. That is, I'm using `\DeclareMathAlphabet`. So, it does not *appear* to be necessary to substitute `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet` as [egreg does](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257016/).

What puzzled me yesterday - and still puzzles me now - is that copying this code does *not* allow me to reproduce the error. So I think the incompatibility must lie elsewhere.

## EDIT EDIT

The code above also allows loading the `mathalfa` package with other options e.g. `cal=boondox` except for the definition of `\mathbfrak`. In order to use that line, you need to undo the existing definition first:

```
\usepackage[cal=boondox]{mathalfa}
\makeatletter
\def\mathalfa@frakscaled{s*[1.0]}
  \DeclareFontFamily{U}{BOONDOX-frak}{\skewchar \font =45}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{BOONDOX-frak}{m}{n}{
    <-> \mathalfa@frakscaled  BOONDOX-r-frak}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{BOONDOX-frak}{b}{n}{
    <-> \mathalfa@frakscaled  BOONDOX-b-frak}{}
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{U}{BOONDOX-frak}{m}{n}
  \SetMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{bold}{U}{BOONDOX-frak}{b}{n}
  \let\mathbfrak\relax
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbfrak} {U}{BOONDOX-frak}{b}{n}
\makeatother
```

But I'm not at all sure that any of this should work this way - either the bits which work or the bits which don't!

Comment: I am very grateful for your answer and your edit. It saves me hours of work ! The cause of the problem is quite narrowed now, even if it is yet not perfectly explained. Nevertheless I accept your answer as such. I choose not to change too much my initial MWE to show the progress made by your analysis, not by me.

Comment: @brunoh -- what is the actual problem?  if `mathalfa` is incompatible with `amsart`, i would like to be able to document this for other users of ams document classes.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Compilation fails with the error given in the question. Changing font size, typesetting something in maths mode and then using `\mathfrak` in the argument to `\section` causes the error. It is quite specific: I can't get a more minimal example than the one I posted. But it does not need to be `\scriptsize`: `\small` also fails. `\normalsize` is fine, though. But issuing `\normalsize` doesn't help if I've used `\scriptsize` first. Switching to `article` resolves the problem - but so does any of the other changes mentioned in my comments on the code.

Comment: @cfr -- i'm not able to test or to look into either `amsart.cls` or `mathalfa.sty` from where i am.  however, on thinking about where i've seen the reported error message, i would try inserting `\protect` before `\mathfrak`.  the math font changing commands in the ams packages are (unfortunately) not robust, and `\section` has a moving argument.  so this may be the problem (and it has nothing to do with `mathalfa`; `amsmath` and `amsfonts` are automatically loaded by `amsart`).  the `\scriptsize` problem is something different though.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I already tried `\protect` but it doesn't help. Note that if `\scriptsize` is not used earlier, `\mathfrak` inside `\section` is not a problem. If the `frak` option for `mathalfa` is not used, there's no problem. If `mathalfa` is not used, there's no problem.

Comment: @cfr -- i seem to remember that if the document text begins with a "nonstandard" math font or size, `amsart' has a problem.  i'll check this on the bugs list when i get back to the office (qugust 4); until then, i'm just guessing.  thanks for the further info; will help when i start digging.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I was away from computer for a while but cfr answered well your questions. To summarize I think cfr is right : there is a conflict between amsart and mathalfa only activated when trying to build the TOC (second typesetting fails not the first) after using \small and then \mathfrak (no need for this command to be issued in \section ...) provided \frak is an option of mathalfa.

Comment: @brunoh I cannot reproduce if it is not within `\section{}`. Otherwise, it does not make it into to ToC.

Comment: @barbarabeeton If `abc` is the first thing in the document, so that the first font used is the normal font in normal size, I still get the error. This also happens if I start with `abc $a$` so that there is some maths set at normal size before switching font sizes.

Comment: @cfr You are right. It was a mistake form me coming from the use of old aux files immediately after changes. Sorry about that. I edit ted my question following your advice.

Comment: @brunoh I am even more puzzled now...

Comment: @barbarabeeton I can't make sense of what worked for me in light of egreg's explanation of the problem. Is that diagnosis right? Am I misunderstanding something in the edits I posted above?

Comment: @cfr -- i think egreg's explanation makes excellent sense.  i've been following the discussions about changes to the latex core effective with tex live 2015 and have been expecting problems like this, owing to the failure to update the various ams classes and packages for so long.  it seems that results will vary depending on whether you've upgraded to tex live 2015 or are still using an older distribution.  investigating this is high on my list for when i return to the office (august 4).

Comment: @cfr I understand your puzzlement. As I said in one of my comment to egreg, his second workaround was nice because I can still used amsfonts and mathalfa packages with all the options. As you notice in your own second edit of your answer, if you keep the same \DeclareMathAlphabet I can not anymore.

Comment: @cfr To explain why your first edit works without contradicting egreg analysis, it is still a bit of a mystery for me : perhaps the effect of the mathalfa code directly in the document is different on the global assignments processes ?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm using TeX Live 2015 updated several hours ago. So I don't think the discrepancy can be explained by egreg's using a later version.

Comment: @brunoh Maybe. Notice that I'm still using `\DeclareMathAlphabet` for `\mathfrak`, though. But `\usepackage{}` is essentially `\input` as I understand it (with some additional checks etc.) and that should be just like having the code in the file.

Comment: @cfr -- i've flagged this question for investigation when i get back to office.  don't have the resources here to do much at all but guess, and my crystal ball is more like rutilated quartz than anything with clarity.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Fair enough - didn't mean to go on about it. [At least you *have* a crystal ball... ;).]

Comment: This problem with mathalpha still exists in TL2023. Interesting that TL2019 doesn't breaks.